# Why calling an async function in a loop doesn't work properly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote this simple program to test some Future features of Dart. I was expecting that when I ran the code, numbers from 1 to 10 print on the console after 2 seconds (not even in order), and then the lope will stop working after *some unkown* time. I know (or knew) how async functions work but this just blew my mind.
And the interesting thing is that the program **NEVER** halts. It just slowly consume 90% of my system memory and sits there doing nothing.
Can someone explain to me what is going on?

```dart
import 'dart:async';

int i = 0;
Future<String> getData() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      i++;
      return 'Hello No.${i}\n';
    });
  }
void main(){
  while(i < 10){
      getData().then((value){
        print(value);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just that you increment `i` after your 2 seconds delay, imagine how many times it can loop within those 2 seconds. It is basically an infinite loop.

Below I refactored your code to have 2 distincts int allowing creating only 10 loops and keeping track of the index at the same time. You also could have passed the `i` to your future or a bunch of other solutions.

```
int index = 0;

Future<String> getData() {
   return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      index++;
      return 'Hello No.${index}\n';
   });
}

void main(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     getData().then((value){
        print(value);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I actually liked your answer better than the others.

Answer (score 0):

The `getData()` function returns a `Future<String>` that completes with a value after 2 seconds.

In your `while` loop, you synchonously create 10 of these futures that you then print the result of.

This code will synchonously (effectively instantly) create 10 of those futures, which will all complete in 2 seconds (roughly) and print their values.

If you want to make each future wait for the previous one to finish, make `main()` an `async` function, then await each call to `getData()`.

Comment: I add a comment under the previous post. Make sure to read it. My problem is that the code never halts and not one of those promises resolves. No print, no incrementing _i_. nothing. I didn't expect it to print every number in order after one another with 2 second delay in between, but I expected that _some_ of those promises resolve and the code halts after _some_ unknown time.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't **wait** `getData()` done before you get to the next loop.
It will cause `getData()` run as many time as it could if the i is under 10. Try to add `await` keyword:

```
void main() async {
  while(i < 10){
    await getData().then((value){
      print(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know adding an async keyword will solve the code.My problem is that the loop never Halts. It never ends. Yes, I'm creating many Futures along the way but why is that there is not a single print in the output?? Why is that none of those Futures never resolve?

Comment: Hi, is your actual question is what happens when app running out of memory? I think the code can't reach the print before it runs out of memory. I try it on dartpad and it surely crashed. It may be an unknown world when the code is un-controllable on different systems.

Comment: Yes and No. I want to know why nothing happens. And what you and @Wappaz are suggesting makes sense to some extent. Is there a way to follow the stack trace of the program?

Comment: Sorry, that's not my expertise. Maybe you can make your question more clear(including the title) and add some system environment information (like flutter doctor -v) to some expert to respond.